# C# Complex object containing dictionary<string,bool> XML deserialization issue

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

XML to be deserialized:

```
<CheckOnlineStatus xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Lifecare.LIS.Integration.Hyland.Models">
  <Database>string</Database>
  <InstancesStillNearline>0</InstancesStillNearline>
  <SeriesLocationMap xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringboolean>
      <d2p1:Key>test</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>true</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringboolean>
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringboolean>
      <d2p1:Key>test1</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>false</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringboolean>
  </SeriesLocationMap>
  <Status>string</Status>
  <StudyInstanceUID>string</StudyInstanceUID>
  <TotalClips>0</TotalClips>
  <TotalExecutionTime>0</TotalExecutionTime>
  <TotalInstances>0</TotalInstances>
</CheckOnlineStatus>
```

Data Models used:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("CheckOnlineStatus")]
/// <summary>
/// The CheckOnlineStatus entity.
/// </summary>
public class CheckOnlineStatus
{
    [XmlElement("Status")]
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Status
    /// </summary>
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Database")]
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Database
    /// </summary>
    public string Database { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the StudyInstanceUID
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("StudyInstanceUID")]
    public string StudyInstanceUID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the TotalExecutionTime
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("TotalExecutionTime")]
    public long TotalExecutionTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the TotalInstances
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("TotalInstances")]
    public int TotalInstances { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the TotalClips
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("TotalClips")]
    public int TotalClips { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the InstancesStillNearline
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("InstancesStillNearline")]
    public int InstancesStillNearline { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the dictionary of series location map
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("SeriesLocationMap")]
    public Dictionary<string, bool> SeriesLocationMap { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization code, here result is above xml in string format:

```
(CheckOnlineStatus)new XmlSerializer(typeof(CheckOnlineStatus)).Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result)));
```

I am getting below runtime error:

> Cannot serialize member
> Lifecare.LIS.Integration.NDP.Models.CheckOnlineStatus.SeriesLocationMap
> of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String,
> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Boolean, mscorlib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]],
> because it implements IDictionary.

I tried couple of other things but it did not worked out e.g. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/716556/XML-deserialize-Attributes-to-dictionary

Can someone please help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception (`InvalidOperationException` with an inner `UnsupportedException`) says you can't simply deserialize it into a `Dictionary`.

Here is one way to overcome of this difficulty:

### Define KeyValue

```cs
[Serializable]
public struct KeyValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

As an alternative you might take advantage of the built-in `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`

### Use `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem`

```cs
[XmlArray("SeriesLocationMap")]
[XmlArrayItem("KeyValueOfstringboolean")]
public List<KeyValue> IntermediateContainer { get; set; }
```

### Use `XmlIgnore` to convert List to `Dictionary<string, bool>`

```cs
[XmlIgnore]
public Dictionary<string, bool> SeriesLocationMap  => IntermediateContainer.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

I've tested it without namespaces, so you need to specify them at the right place to be able to read them properly.

---

Alternatively you might give it a try and use `DataContractSerializer` which [does support Dictionary](https://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/net-tips-xml-serialize-or-deserialize-dictionary-in-csharp/).

Comment: thanks. DataSerializer fixed issue for us